# String ending in range of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column with data of the following structure:

```
aaa5644988
aaa4898494
aaa5642185
aaa5482312
aaa4648848
```

I have a range that can be anything, like 100-30000 or example. I want to have all values that end in numbers between that range.

I tried

```
like '%[100-30000]'
```

but this doesn't work apparently.

I have seen a lot of similar questions but none of the solved my problem

edit I'm using SQL server 2008

Example:

```
Value
aaa45645695
aaa28568720
aaa65818450
8789212
6566700
```

For the range 600-1200, I want to retrieve row 1,2,5 because they end with the range.

Comment: Does your RDBMS support regex matching? (Note even if it does you are most likely going to get *horrible* performance out of this kind of query)

Comment: Is there a pattern with all the prefix (length), maybe substring the value and cast it to int and then you can use between

Comment: That doesn't make sense.. how many digits do you want to test? Please give example output.

Comment: Can you change this table? Then i would strongly suggest to use two columns.

Comment: Is the prefix part always the same length? What about the number part?

Comment: The table cannot be changed, I've been thinking about creating a view with the reverse string to match the start. The prefix has a pattern, but is not forced so I've seen already a few rows with the wrong formatting.

Comment: What are the other values like, ones you don't want to select?

Comment: @Kuzgun  I have added an example

Comment: With your example data, if you wanted to select 700-5700, which rows would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, `like` normally only support `%` and `_` these two operators. That's why `like '%[100-30000]'` doesn't work.

Depend on your use case, there could be two solutions for this problem:

If you only need to do this query two or three times(didn't care how long it takes), or the dataset is not very big. You can select all the data from this column, and then do the filtering in another programming language.

Take ruby for example, you can do:

```
column_data = @connection.execute("select * from your_column_name")
result = column_data.map{|x| x.gsub(/^.*[^\d]/, '').to_i }.select{|x| x > 100 && x < 30000}
```

If you need to do this query regularly, I'd suggest you add a new column to this data table with only the numbers in the current column, so as to get a much better performance in querying speed.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   your_table 
WHERE  number_column BETWEEN 100 AND 30000
```

Comment: It will not run a whole lut, but quite regularly. There is lots of data (500.000+ rows)

Comment: Then I really suggest you add a new column for this. Casting the format and calculating the range in real time & in memory is always time consuming.

Comment: It's really not an option to add a column. I could create an indexed view. The between operator would not work because the string is longer than the search string

Comment: Maybe you can try to use a search system(Apache solr, lucene etc) to do this kind querying. It will be much faster. Or you can implement a special index system for your problem.

Comment: I accepted your answer. What I eventually did was I found out that every value ended in 8 numbers. They searched for 8 numbers every time too. I created an indexed view in which I took the last 8 characters and matched them with the range. The performance of this query is as exptected.